# How can i enable my Camera to take picture programatically in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I do not want my app to call native Camera app. All I want is to enable my app to take pics programatically when the app starts without any user interaction or involvement.

Here is my code:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{


     Camera camera;
     PictureCallback rawCallback;
     ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
     PictureCallback jpegCallback;
     ImageView view;

     boolean inPreview = false;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.pic);

        Log.e("Camera Status: ",String.valueOf(checkCameraHardware(getApplicationContext())));
        Log.e("Number Of Cameras: ",String.valueOf(Camera.getNumberOfCameras()));

        start_camera();
        captureImage();

         rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
                }
            };

            /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
            shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
                public void onShutter() {
                    Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
                }
            };

            jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
                public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                    //Set the Image to ImageView
                    Bitmap bitmapPicture
                   = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length); 
                    //view.setImageBitmap(bitmapPicture);

                //Save the Image to SD Card 
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                                "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();
                        Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");



                    /**
                     * The two lines below are used to refresh the Surface View 
                     * It works quickly then the general refresh by Default
                     **/
                    stop_camera();
                    start_camera();
                }
            };

        //start_camera();

    }


    /** Check if this device has a camera */
    private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
        }
        return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
    }


      private void start_camera()
        {
            try{
                camera = Camera.open();
                Log.e("Camera Open Status: ", "Camera opened successfully");
            }catch(RuntimeException e){
                Log.e("Camera Initialization:", "init_camera: " + e);
                return;
            }
            Camera.Parameters param;
            param = camera.getParameters();
            //modify parameter
            param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
            param.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
            camera.setParameters(param);
            try {
                //camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
                //camera.takePicture(shutter, raw, jpeg)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Camera Initialization:", "init_camera: " + e);
                return;
            }
            inPreview=true;
        }


      private void captureImage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, true);

            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            Log.e("Picture Status: ","picture taken successfully");
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                        mgr.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM, false);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                }, 1000); 


        }

      private void stop_camera()
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.release();
            inPreview = false;
        }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your problem in this code ?. I have created library you can check it out https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project

Comment: The camera does not take picture. Also I am getting a null pointer exception.

Comment: at where you got NPE? post ur logcat.

Comment: Did you use my project ? and where is the error coming at ? Pls paste the logcat too

Comment: @PiyushGupta Please check logcat in my edited question.

Comment: @GirishNair Can you please guide me on how to use the library? I haven't downloaded it and looked into it though. I just want the camera to take pic the moment the app starts and thats it.

Comment: @GirishNair Please check my latest comment under your answer. Also can you explain why do I need to override this method: pictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap, File file) ?

Answer (score 1):

Download the project form [here](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/archive/master.zip)
Copy the **CameraLibrary** into your workspace

Add these to your manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-features android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<activity android:name="com.girish.cameraLibrary.CameraClass"></activity>
```

Now in your activity implement the `com.girish.cameraLibrary.OnPictureTaken` interface and Override the `pictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap, File file)` method which provides your with the bitmap and File

Now Create and instance of the CustomCamera

```
private CustomCamera mCustomCamera;

mCustomCamera = new CustomCamera(MainActivity.this);
mCustomCamera.setPictureTakenListner(this);

//To start the custom back camera use this
mCustomCamera.startCamera();
//To send an intent to applications who are listening to Camera request
mCustomCamera.sendCameraIntent();
//To start the front camera use this
mCustomCamera.startCameraFront();
```

The now you can access the image using `pictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap, File file)` method, so just use

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

***EDIT***

Suppose your main class is called `MainActivity` the write like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnPictureTaken {

.....
.....
.....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
.....
.....


//This is where you get the picture
@Override
public void pictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap, File file) {
    imgCapture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    txtPath.setText(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Check the sample file as mentioned [here](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/blob/master/Girish%20Camera%20Library%20Project/CameraSample/src/com/example/camerasample/MainActivity.java)

Comment: Is `startCameraInbuit` a typo in your answer or in the library?

Comment: Its not a type,its sending an intent for all those who are listening to camera. I need to change that name

Comment: By "typo" I meant typographical error - a spelling mistake - in the method name. I assumed it should be `startCameraInbuilt` (note the "L")

Comment: Ya it was a typo sorry, but anyway I corrected the name

Comment: @GirishNair How will I override this method pictureTaken(Bitmap bitmap, File file) ? Please provide complete code.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman : have you never once written any listners before ?? . Anyway check my edit

Comment: @GirishNair There is no such method as sendCameraIntent() in the CustomCamera class. Your library as well the code posted here are incomplete. Ensure to test the code at your end.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman:Ensure you download the latest code, check here its already posted,

https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/blob/master/Girish%20Camera%20Library%20Project/CameraSample/src/com/example/camerasample/MainActivity.java

https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/blob/master/Girish%20Camera%20Library%20Project/CameraLibrary/src/com/girish/cameraLibrary/CustomCamera.java

I had updated code yesterday only, you can check it from the branch history https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/commits/master

Comment: @GirishNair I just require one link from where I can download the complete code. What is that link? Also provide a complete working demo of demonstration of using your library.

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman : I have already provided it in answer, here it is https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project/archive/master.zip , It also has a sample project

Comment: @GirishNair Fine. I see. By sample project you mean the code demonstrating what I am after(as the question says) here exactly. Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadMaqsoodurRehman : Yes, use `mCustomCamera.startCamera();` method